# How can I stop execution of javascript function until user action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await, promise

So im trying to replicate the window.confirm() prompt in javascript. here is the structure of what i tried.

```
function foo(){
    if(customConfirm("Click yes or no"))
        alert("Clicked yes");
    else
        alert("Clicked no");
}

function customConfirm(message){
    $('#customConfirm').load("customAlert.html");
    $('#okButton').click(function(e){
        ret = true;
    })
    $('#cancelButton').click(function(e){
        ret = false;
    })
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript you don't stop execution of functions, you use event handlers that take action when the user does something.

Comment: Take a look at how the Sweet Alert library does this.

Comment: Please explain what is the issue with your code you're facing currently. I don't understand how is your *general* `foo` function related to it.

Comment: The only issue I se here is that you dynamically load some HTML view, but even before the loading is done you're trying to assign events to (currently) unexistent elements. You might want to take a look at Event .on() with dynamic binding or either at a .load() success callback

Answer (score -1):

If you're using raw JS, or at most JQuery instead of say React, Vue, etc., I would provide callbacks for the "customConfirm" so that say when you detect a button press on Ok and Cancel, and call each callback accordingly. This would require the use of event handlers which is fairly basic with raw JS, and even more so with JQuery...

Here's a basic idea of what I'm saying (forgive me if the code is incorrect, I haven't used JQuery let alone frontend JS in some time now.

```js
function displayConfirm() {
    // Let's pretend the confirm "modal" has two buttons, one with id "okButton" and the other with "cancelButton". We shall use this later.
}

function updatePage(cancelled) {
    // Here is where we would update the page depending on whether or not the confirm was cancelled. 
}
$('#okButton').click(function() { // We don't use e, so we're just gonna ignore it... I think you can anyways, if JQuery throws a fit, use _ instead of e for the variable name as it just tells JS "hey, this variable, we don't use it."
    updatePage(false);
}); // Consistently use semicolons, look into ESLint if you're forgetful like me lol
$('#cancelButton').click(function() {
    updatePage(true);
});
```

It's as simple as that. Since JS doesn't allow you to just pause execution like that (well you can, but it just freezes everything else, such as when you don't ever break from an infinite loop, or recurse with no exit condition (unless JS does a Python and has a recursion limit)), we use just a callback for when that event is received. So unfortnately afaik you can't really wrap this into a function... Aside of maybe using promises? I don't think you can but it may be worth some research if you really, for whatever reason insist on using a function to wrap it all.